# 9-patch background in horizontal recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, nine-patch

I am using a horizontal RecyclerView:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/chronology_rv_players"/>
```

which contains several of the following CardViews:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp">

        ...

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="0dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_player_list_right"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/background_player_right"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:padding="0dp"/>

                ...

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The drawable "background_player_right" is the following 9-patch image:

[image]

However, the 9-patch image does not stretch until the right end of the CardView image:

[image]

I think this is due to the fact that I am using an horizontal RecyclerView (similarly I was not able to align text to the right of a CardView) but I don't know how obtain the expected results.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the ImageView and set the 9 patch directly to the background of your RelativeLayout.